# How to resolve ERROR: cannot read command from socket, code 10054

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I am trying to create a read and write operation for a server that I did not create.

The write operation works but for the read operation I am getting :

> ERROR: cannot read command from socket, code 10054(This appears in the SERVER LOG and my app hangs)

If I use the example from the Microsoft website it works as expected out of the box [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=net-7.0) but when I modify the Microsft example I get the error above. My modification is below.

I don't want to keep opening and closing connections for every command(I am not knowledgeable in this area, so is that advisable?)

How does this communication work:

1. Is it that if I send command 1 command 2 won't send until we get a response from command 1?
2. Can TCP commands be sent simultaneously? If so how can I make sure the response I get belongs to the right command? The reason why I am asking I would like to check if a command fails and if it does try again.

C# Class:

```
public class TCPConnection : IConnection
{
    public TCPConnection(MachineInfo machineInfo) => this.MachineInfo = machineInfo as MachineInfo;

    TcpClient TcpClient ;
    private NetworkStream Stream;
    private readonly MachineInfo MachineInfo;

    public void Connect()
    {
        Disconnect();
        TcpClient = new TcpClient();
        TcpClient.Connect(hostname: MachineInfo.IPAddress, this.MachineInfo.Port);
        Stream = TcpClient.GetStream();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        TcpClient?.Close();
        Stream?.Close();
    }

    public string ReadData(string message)
    {
        WriteData(message);
        data = new Byte[256];
        String responseData = String.Empty;
     
        Int32 bytes = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        return responseData;
    }
    Byte[] data;
    public void WriteData(string message)
    {
        
        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        Stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var v= new  TCPConnection(new MachineInfo("127.0.0.1",8900));
v.Connect();

var AllCommands = new List<string>();
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("cmd1");
AllCommands.Add("This could go up to 1000");

foreach (var item in AllCommands)
{
    var test = v.ReadData(item);
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}

v.Disconnect();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You said exception happens at your server, but this looks like client code.

Comment: @Evk Yes, This is all client code. The only issue with the client code is that it hangs on Int32 bytes = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);. The server that I did not write has a log when I check the Server log I see the error message.